# How do I iterate over a vector of strings stored in a struct without moving them?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I have a large struct that has a vector of `String`s as a member.  I am trying to iterate over these and pass each to another method that takes a `&str` argument.  The latter method requires `&mut self` in order to process an input stream, and I can't seem to reconcile the borrows.

I boiled this down to a simple (?) example that shows the issue I have.  See below, and also a link to a [the code on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0c38e88eff7a0d9d7a8a553912d4654)

```rust
pub struct Configuration {
    pub prefixes: Vec<String>,
}

impl Configuration {
    pub fn check_one(&mut self, prefix: &str) -> bool {
        "testy".starts_with(prefix)
    }
    pub fn check(&mut self) -> bool {
        for prefix in &self.prefixes {
            if self.check_one(prefix) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut config = Configuration{ prefixes: vec!["fl".to_string()], };
    dbg!(config.check());
}
```

The actual question.  If I make the argument a reference (`self.check_one(&prefix)`) then I get an issue that `self.prefixes` is moved by `into_iter()`, and the compiler recommends `&self.prefixes`.  Fine.  But if I try *that*, I'm told that I cannot borrow `self` immutably when I have already borrowed it mutably, and I cannot seem to reconcile these two.

Bottom line is that I need to pass each `String` in a member vector to a method to check.  I don't want the string or vector to be modified, but I have to borrow `&self` as mutable.  Suggestions?

Comment: Mutable references are not needed in the simple example you provided. Please consider refactoring it to match your need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to call a method that takes `&mut self` when part of `self` is borrowed. That's because a method taking `&mut self` is allowed to modify any part of `self`. You can't make a *method* that's allowed to modify only a part of `self`.

As written, `check_one` should take `&self`. Inside `check`, `&mut self` will automatically convert to `&self` on calling `check_one`.

```rs
pub fn check_one(&self, prefix: &str) -> bool {
    "testy".starts_with(prefix)
}
```

If you need to be able to modify all parts of `self`, including `prefixes`, then you need to clone `prefixes` so that the copy `self` owns is not borrowed.

```rs
for prefix in &self.prefixes.clone() {
    if self.check_one(prefix) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you don't need mutable or immutable access to `prefixes`, then you can do one of two things. First, you could make a regular function that takes the other parts of `self`.

```rs
// Replace `()` with the other parts of `self`
pub fn check_one(_other_parts: (), prefix: &str) -> bool {
    "testy".starts_with(prefix)
}
```

```rs
for prefix in &self.prefixes {
    if check_one((), prefix) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or you can temporarily [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) `prefixes` from `self`, and put it back when done.

```rs
pub fn check(&mut self) -> bool {
    let prefixes = std::mem::take(&mut self.prefixes);
    for prefix in &prefixes {
        if self.check_one(prefix) {
            self.prefixes = prefixes;
            return true;
        }
    }
    self.prefixes = prefixes;
    return false;
}
```

Lastly, a less common case is when `check_one` may or may not modify `prefixes` depending on the data. In that case, in order to only clone `prefixes` when necessary, you can use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html). This is a more extensive change.

```rs
pub struct Configuration {
    pub prefixes: Rc<Vec<String>>,
}

impl Configuration {
    pub fn check_one(&mut self, prefix: &str) -> bool {
        let check = "testy".starts_with(prefix);
        // Do some mutable work
        if check {
            Rc::make_mut(&mut self.prefixes).push("new".to_string());
        }
        return check;
    }

    pub fn check(&mut self) -> bool {
        // The only change needed here is a dereference
        for prefix in &*self.prefixes.clone() {
            if self.check_one(prefix) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When you clone the `Rc` itself, it creates a second read-only reference that points to the same data. Calling [`make_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut) will clone the data when there is more than one reference alive, giving you mutable access to the data. In this case, the first time `make_mut` is called, the data will be cloned, the `Rc` will replace itself with a new `Rc` containing the cloned data, and a mutable reference will be returned. If `make_mut` is called again in the same loop, it will simply return a mutable reference, since it's no longer linked to the other `Rc`.